# Android Studio icons such as AVD, Run, debug, etc are unavailable (grey)

Tags: android, android-studio

Pretty much what the title says. I am sorry if the question seems naive, but today is the first day I am starting learning android development and I am extremely unfamiliar with this feature-heavy IDE as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

press Alt+u or Click Run on the menu, then select 'Edit Configuration' option.
then click on Android Application on the left and click the on top-left + button.
Choose Android Application from the pop-up menu. after that select module like app then click on apply and ok.

Comment: The only option next to "Module" is <no module>. Since I added "Android App", Run and Debug became available. AVD Manager is still grey, though.